# How to fix using 'andalso' and ',' in Erlang's guard tests

Tags: erlang

In the book Learn You Some Erlang for Great Good, it's said "the best strategy is often to mix them as necessary" about 'andalso', 'orelse', ',' and ';'.
So, I try to coding like this, but it's compiled failure.

```
right_age(X) when (X>=18,X=<60) orelse (X=:=9) -> true;
right_age(_) -> false.
```

Please give me a right example, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See the definition [here](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id84520):

> A guard sequence is a sequence of guards, separated by semicolon (;). The guard sequence is true if at least one of the guards is true. (The remaining guards, if any, are not evaluated.)
>
> ```
> Guard1;...;GuardK
> ```
>
> A guard is a sequence of guard expressions, separated by comma (,). The guard is true if all guard expressions evaluate to true.
>
> ```
> GuardExpr1,...,GuardExprN
> ```

So you can't have guard-separating `,` inside `orelse` as in your original code. The normal way to write your guard would be `when X>=18, X=<60; X=:=9`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the following compiles:

```
-module(my).
-export([right_age/1]).

right_age(X) when (X>=18),(X=<60 orelse X=:=9) -> 
    true;
right_age(_) -> 
    false.
```

A guard is of the form

```
expression punctuation expression
```

But your guard does this:

```
 (X>=18,X=<60) ->
```

where the parentheses are straddling the punctuation, and apparently parentheses have a higher precedence than the punctuation, so the parentheses form one expression, and your guard is of the form:

```
   expres punctuation sion
```

No good: it doesn't compile.  So it looks like the rule is: ***parentheses cannot straddle the guard punctuation***.

An expression in the guard can also be a *compound boolean expression*, for instance:

```
 X=<60 orelse X=:=9
```

> Though, I don't know the reason, but it's compiled success.
>
> ```
> right_age(X) when (X>=18 andalso X=<60) ; (X=:=9) -> true;
> right_age(_) -> false.
> ```

Let's take a look:

```
 compound_boolean_expression     expression
                 |                 |
                 V                 V
   when (X>=18 andalso X=<60) ; (X=:=9)
                              ^
                              |
                          punctuation
```

So, you have:

```
  compound_boolean_expression punctuation expression
```

That's legal.  Note that you don't need the parentheses:

```
right_age(X) when X>=18 andalso X=<60; X=:=9 -> 
    true;
right_age(_) -> 
    false.
```

Answer (score 0):

Though, I don't know the reason, but it's compiled success.

```
right_age(X) when (X>=18 andalso X=<60) ; (X=:=9) -> true;
right_age(_) -> false.
```